# Get constant interval of ticks value in d3.scaleTime()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsaleem/8tmLrb9t/5/)

I need to get a constant interval of ticks values between any random date using ***d3.scaleTime()*** and plot in an axis.

But

```
timeScale.nice(intervalValue);
//or 
axisXScale.tickValues(timeScale.ticks(10));
```

doesnt help , I am always getting random number of ticks values.

As per D3 documentation

```
# continuous.ticks([count])

Returns approximately count representative values from the scale’s domain. If count is not specified, it defaults to 10.
The returned tick values are uniformly spaced, have human-readable values (such as multiples of powers of 10), and are guaranteed to be within the extent of the domain.
Ticks are often used to display reference lines, or tick marks, in conjunction with the visualized data.
The specified count is only a hint; the scale may return more or fewer values depending on the domain.
```

So is there any way we can get a constant number rather than approximation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsaleem/8tmLrb9t/7/)

So I just went with the approach of having a reverse time scale and find the date from the x value.

```
  var timeScaleReverse = d3.scaleTime().range([start, end]).domain([0, width]);

  timeScale.nice(intervalValue);

  var tickValues = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < width; i += (width/intervalValue)) {
    tickValues.push(new Date(timeScaleReverse(i)));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to do something like this:

```
.ticks(d3.timeMonth.every(1))
```

For more details at http://www.d3noob.org/2016/08/changing-number-of-ticks-on-axis-in.html.

Hope this help!

Comment: But how we can get a consistent number between any two dates with `d3.timeMonth`

Comment: You can use it like: d3.axisBottom(timeScale).tickSize(0).ticks(d3.timeMonth.every(1))

Comment: If I have one-year interval it will give 12 and if  its 6 month interval its 6, What i want is in all cases a constant number

Comment: Try again with  *timeScale.nice(d3.timeMonth,intervalValue);* Maybe here is what you want to see: http://jsfiddle.net/hbnjaoL8/?

Comment: It still have the issue of rounding number of values not exactly the number what we want.